# Is this Django Middleware Thread-safe?

Tags: django, python-2.6, django-1.4

I am writing forum app on Django using custom session/auth/users/acl system. One of goals is allowing users to browse and use my app even if they have cookies off. Coming from PHP world, best solution for problem is appending sid= to every link on page. Here is how I plan to do it:

Session middleware checks if user has session cookie or remember me cookie. If he does, this most likely means cookies work for him. If he doesnt, we generate new session ID, open new session (make new entry in sessions table in DB), then send cookie and redirect user to where he is, but with SID appended to url. After redirect middleware will see if session id can be obtained from either cookie or GET. If its cookie, we stop adding sid to urls. If its GET, we keep them.

I plan to insert SID= part into url's by decorating django.core.urlresolvers.reverse and reverse_lazy with my own function that appends ?sid= to them. However this raises some problems because both middlewares urlresolvers and are not thread safe. To overcome this I created something like this:

```
class SessionMiddleware(object):
    using_decorator = False
    original_reverse = None

    def process_request(self, request):        
        self.using_decorator = True
        self.original_reverse = urlresolvers.reverse
        urlresolvers.reverse = session_url_decorator(urlresolvers.reverse, 's87add8ash7d6asdgas7dasdfsadas')

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # Turn off decorator if we are using it
        if self.using_decorator:
            urlresolvers.reverse = self.original_reverse
            self.using_decorator = False
        return response
```

If SID has to be passed via links, process_request sets using_decorator to true and stores undecorated urlresolvers.revers in separate method. After page is rendered process_response checks using_decorator to see if it has to perform "garbage collection". If it does, it returns reverse function to original undecorated state.

My question is, is this approach thread-safe? Or will increase in traffic on my forum may result in middleware decorating those functions again and again and again, failing to run "garbage collection"? I also tought about using regex to simply skim generated HTML response for links and providing template filters and variables for manually adding SID to places that are omitted by regex.

Which approach is better? Also is current one thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Using SIDs in the URL is quite dangerous, eg if you copy&paste a link for a friend he is signed in as you. Since most users don't know what a SID is they will run into this issue. As such you should never ever use SIDs in the url and since Facebook and friends all require cookies you should be fine too...

Considering that, monkeypatching urlresolvers.reverse luckily doesn't work! Might be doable with a custom URLResolvers subclass, but I recommend against it.

And yes, your middleware is not threadsafe. Middlewares are initialized only once and shared between threads, meaning that storing anything on self is **not** threadsafe.

Comment: My issue comes from online lists and online counters. When you are visited by user who doesnt do cookies you eventually end with online counter being ridiculously big, as every request from him opens new session. I think I will counter it by displaying and counting only users who have "matched" field set to true, ergo those who made second request that successfully matched session.